# Load properties selectively from properties file based on key value

Tags: java, properties, namespaces

I have a property file which has values like

```
xxx.key1 = value1
xxx.key2 = value2

yyy.key3 = value3
yyy.key4 = value4
```

`'xxx'` and `'yyy'` can be considered as 2 different namespaces. 
How do I load property file so that I can only load either property of `'xxx'` or `'yyy'`?

Comment: Why not using two separated properties files?

Comment: We want to keep the number of files where user has to configure to 1. Other wise the configuration gets scattered at multiple places

Answer (score 0):

Just read each line of the file and only pull back the values that match that namespace.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("yourfilepath"));
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
String value = "";
while(scan.hasNext())
{
    value = scan.nextLine();
    if(value.indexOf("xxx") != -1)
    {
        map.put(value.split(" = ")[0], value.split(" = ")[1]);
    }
}

//now map has your key value pairs
```

If your properties are like this

xxx.key1=value
then in the split("=") (no spaces)